# Hypergeometric function hiding a symmetry

Tags: combinatorics, special-functions

Consider the following function:

$f(a,b,c)=\frac{1}{[1 + 2(a + c)][1 + 2(b + c)]}\,_3F_2 \left[ \begin{array}{l}
1,  1/2-c, -c \\ 
1/2 - a - c,  1/2 - b - c
\end{array} ; 1\right]  $

with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$.

I can be checked (for instance on Wolfram Mathematica) that $f(a,b,c)$ is a symmetric in its arguments. This is evident for $a \leftrightarrow b$ but it is far from obvious, for instance, when it comes to $a \leftrightarrow c$.

Suppose you don't know $f$ is symmetric. Is it possible to rewrite $f$ in a form where the symmetry property is evident for all possible exchanges?

Thanks

Comment: I do not think it is necessary to write it as a hypergeometric function. Note that the third argument in the first line, i.e. $-c$, ensures that it is always a *finite* sum as the Pochhammer Symbol (which is usually applied to define the generalized hypergeometric function) vanishs as soon as the index exceeds $c$.

Comment: This is highly reminiscent of [Dixon's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_identity)---or, rather, the first generalization thereof listed in the Wikipedia page. (Note the explicit permutation symmetry among $a,b,c$.)

Comment: @mrtaurho Yes, there is nothing really special about the hypergeometric function in f. We can re-express it in other ways.

Comment: @Semiclassical Dixon's identities work with well-poised hypergeometric functions which is not the case here. The use of the more general MacMahon Master theorem might help but I still haven't figured out how to  implement it here.